# Why is ArcGIS Server so slow in creating mapbook PNG

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, map-book

We have 3 MXDs for creating 3 different mapbooks. Our customer want a daily export to PNG. For this, I use a Python-Script, which works fine for me on my Desktop. But I need it on ArcGIS Server. There it works also, but is really slow. In fact, it takes up to 2.5 times on Server than on Desktop.
Two of the MXDs have to export 173 PNG, the third exports only 32.

Times on Desktop: One of the 'big' MXD (with 173 PNG) needs ca. 5 hours ( ~106 seconds per PNG), but on the Server it needs ca. 12 hours ( ~255 seconds per PNG).

I tried a SDE as datasource (which is the way i normally want to go) and a fGDB. Also Labelling on and off. But there where no specific difference in processing speed.

Server is an ArcGIS Server 10.2.1.

Can anyone give tips for a better processing time or have the same issue? And please, know comments like these mapbooks are too big for a daily export ;)

Another question, if someone have experience with that: How much could multithreading give here?